# Is the difference between and saying 有时 and 会偶尔 very big?

Tags: word-choice, usage, meaning

Does one imply a much greater frequency? What about [register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29)? Is the difference between and saying 有时 and 会偶尔 very big, or is it in all cases quite close?

Comment: 有时 is very formal and can only be found in the written language. 有的时候 is colloquial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, 有时 and 偶尔 are interchangeable under **ANY** circumstances.

Depending on personal preference, feel free to pick either one when expressing *once in a while*.

Comment: My apologies. You should listen to Terry LiYifeng.

Answer (score 0):

To me 有时 feels more like "sometimes" and 偶尔 feels more like "occasionally".